# A pejorative term for "unreasonably gregarious"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, pejorative-language

I am looking for a pejorative term to describe someone who constantly needs social interaction regardless of quality.

Something along the lines of "social nymphomaniac", but not necessarily gender-specific, and preferably in a single word. I would also prefer it if it were not colloquial.

Comment: Did you look in a thesaurus for synonyms of gregarious?

Comment: Yes, and I couldn't find any pejorative terms. Everything was either neutral or complimentary.

Comment: Be metaphorical then. Soul-eater. Social butterfly. Don't limit yourself to one word.

Comment: Hah! But does that mean there is no specific English term to describe such people?

Comment: [Needy](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/needy?q=needy#needy__7) seems to fit.

Comment: I don't know. That's quite a lot to expect of a single word. Extroverted, excessively, pejorative, and all in one word? Just because there are lots of single words for complex ideas doesn't mean that every conceivable complex idea has a corresponding single word. Or I could be wrong.

Comment: I would not have said that "social nymphomaniac" is gender specific, but the most common term for this is ***social whore***.  A single word is not likely to cover all of the connotations although ***tart*** is used colloquially sometimes.

Comment: I gave this a +1 because it seems there ought to be such a word. The best I can think of are words like "sheeple" and "herd," which apply to groups rather than the individuals that constitute them.

Comment: I was basing this question on the fact that there are dozens of synonyms for gregarious, none of which are pejorative. Considering there are multiple synonyms for each of the capital sins, each of which can be seen as a quintessentially human trait, I think the difficulty of finding a single pejorative term for gregarious shows a lot about our society (not that this is a criticism).

Comment: I think it would help if you could describe *when* you would want to use this word.  I can't actually think of why I would describe someone as "unreasonably" gregarious; I suspect anyone who would fit that bill would be better described by a more specific word that addresses why the behavior is viewed negatively.  (For instance, scenester or scenewhore for someone who feels compelled to go to *every* event associated with a particular subculture.)

Comment: You're right, _gregariousness_ is "a quintessentially human trait". Society values extroverts & hates introverts. I met a beautiful, brilliant, & talented Japanese woman in Tokyo: love at 1st sight till I learned she was a "social addict", a _party animal_ who unfailingly socialized in convivial penguinesque coveys immediately after clocking out of her office. That doused the transient flame of desire & squelched my initial inclination to do more than just appreciate from afar the beauty of her countenance.

Comment: The term "social butterfly" comes to my mind.  It is used to describe some women, and it is mildly pejorative, suggesting lots of superficial engagements, but no in-depth or serious ones.  It's an apt metaphor, since butterflies flit from flower to flower and are seldom in one place for very long.

Comment: How about a *monophobe* or *eremophobe*, someone who is afraid of being alone? Because that's really what this is all about, isn't it?
Dictionary.com has [monophobia](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/monophobia). Or how about a *plethophile*, a "lover of groups/masses", or a *polymaniac*, "someone is is crazy about the many"? Or, similarly, *agelomaniac*, a "herd-maniac".

Answer (score 4):

I would call such a person *intrusive*, if I were limited to a single word. Some of the synonyms my thesaurus gives for *intrusive* are *presumptuous*, *pushy*, *impertinent*, *officious*, and *forward*. They're all pejorative. An *officious* person offers help, advice, or service where none is wanted. A *presumptuous* person presumes on a degree of familiarity or intimacy that isn't warranted by the actual relationship. Another word for *forward* in this sense is *brash*.

Comment: Intrusive is exactly what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I was just editing a paper on schizophrenia and noticed that one of the symptoms of the disease is called *[asociality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asociality)*. Being *asocial* (lacking a strong motivation to engage in social interaction or preferring solitary activities) is not the same as being *antisocial* (active dislike or antagonism toward other people or the general social order).

One antonym for *asocial* is *gregarious*. To turn that into a pejorative, you can prefix ***hyper-*** or ***ultra-***.

That'll give you:

> **[hypersocial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypersocial)** and **hypergregarious**

[M-W 3rd Unabridged says: "Main Entry: **hyper-**
Function:prefix 
Etymology:alteration (influenced by Latin hyper-) of Middle English iper-, from Late Latin hyper-, from Latin, from Greek, from *hyper* (more at OVER)

1 : over : above : **beyond** : SUPER- *hyperbarbarous*, *hyperemphasis*
2 : **overmuch** : **excessively** : EXTRA- *hypercritical*, *hypersensitive*
3 a : **excessive** in extent or quality *hyperesthesia*, *hyperemesis*,]

as well as

> **ultrasocial** and **ultragregarious**

[M-W 3rd Unabridged says: "Main Entry: **ultra-**
Function: prefix 
Etymology: Latin, from *ultra* beyond (adverb & preposition), from abl. singular feminine of (assumed) *ulter* situated beyond (more at ULTERIOR)

3 : **beyond what is common, ordinary, natural, right, proper, or moderate : excessively** : exceedingly : HYPER- *ultracomplex*, *ultracritical*, *ultraformal*, *ultramodern*]

The problem with *ultrasocial*, however, is that [Jonathan Heidt](http://socialmediatoday.com/fgossieaux/555863/importance-reciprocity-ultrasocial-societies) and others have approbatorily appropriated the term to describe human and animal ("[social insects and colonial invertebrates](http://www.sscnet.ucla.edu/anthro/faculty/boyd/ultra.pdf)") societies, because most people are social, not asocial or antisocial.

> (#)*Hypersocial and ultra-gregarious* are associated with a neurological problem called [Williams Syndrome#](http://lesswrong.com/lw/xd/growing_up_is_hard/) (#: see next paragraph), so using those terms is probably politically incorrect because it implies that the person they're used to describe is "crazy".

(#)"People with Williams Syndrome (caused by deletion of a certain region on chromosome 7) are **hypersocial, ultra-gregarious**; as children they fail to show a normal fear of adult strangers.  WSers are cognitively impaired on most dimensions, but their verbal abilities are spared or even exaggerated; they often speak early, with complex sentences and large vocabulary, and excellent verbal recall, even if they can never learn to do basic arithmetic."

That leaves only ***[hyper-gregarious](http://rdd.me/uxu34wki)***, which is used in a medical book to describe one clinical symptom seen in some alcoholics.

Another possibility is to coin words like *sociorrhea*, *sociorrheic*, *gregariorrhea*, and *gregariorrheic*, using *[diarrhea](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diarrhea)* and *[logorrhea](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logorrhea)* as models, by adding the suffix *[-rrhea](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rrhea)*. Those two conditions are considered pretty *obnoxious*, I'd say, and are never used with positive connotations.

A little bit of imagination will take you a long way in the world of neologisms.

Comment: Wow. That's a great answer!

Comment: (I'm going to give it a few more days, before I select one though.)

Comment: @TimY: Thank you! My imagination is limited, so I suggest that you do give it a few days. Someone else may come up with something much better. A good question deserves some hard thought before an attempt to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

***"Social addict"***, though 2 words, has the pejorativeness you're looking for, I believe.

Comment: But that's not a phrase that's sees any use.  (A quick google suggests that when it is used, it refers to social media e.g. someone who uses facebook too much.)

Comment: @starwed.  Great!  Another perfectly good phrase usurped by FaceBook and the like! grrr!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think [social butterfly](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Social%20Butterfly) would fit most contexts perfectly well...

> *Someone who is VERY social and easygoing; can be either a male or a female. Usually these people don’t belong to a particular group, but rather jump from one group to another. They are somewhat accepted in all of them, but don’t really have any deep friendship connections in any of them.*

...but if OP doesn't want a "colloquial" term, perhaps [socialite](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=socialite&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=emiiUfq0OsGf0QXSi4GoDA&ved=0CC8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=d3d85859a5844b3f&biw=1269&bih=865) would do...

> *A person who is well known in fashionable society and is fond of social activities and entertainment.*

Comment: I don't think those are pejorative though, unless you're biased against social people as a class.

Comment: @Bradd Szonye: You're joking! I can't imagine anyone thinking "social butterfly" is anything other than pejorative. And as for "socialite" - I doubt very much if anyone would self-identify as one, even if they're not prepared to take out libel actions against gossip-columnists who describe them as such.

Comment: Nope, not joking at all  – maybe it's a regional difference? The Urban Dictionary entry you cite lists positive, neutral, and pejorative senses of _social butterfly_: The neutral–positive ones have net upvotes, the pejoratives have downvotes, and the one you quote actually has a positive, self-descriptive example. I usually see it used to describe people whose popularity or hospitality transcends clique boundaries. I occasionally see it used to suggest shallowness or irresponsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *ultrasociable* will suit your needs. It's not at all colloquial, and any word that begins with *ultra-* is generally pejorative, like *ultraconservative*, *ultraorthodox*, and *ultraliberal*, because *ultra-* means *extreme*.

[Bacchanalian](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bacchanalian) (noun and adjective) or *bacchic* (adjective) might fit, but they are kind of restricted to drunken, orgiastic parties. [Corybantic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corybantic) is another, but it implies wildness too.

Comment: I don't think those last two possibilities are worth even bringing up.  They're pretty far off the mark, and mentioning them might mislead someone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ***"Serial Socializer"***... as in someone who, like a Serial Murderer, can't stop from socializing to the point where he/she becomes a social pariah anywhere that person sets foot in.

Answer (score 0):

I think *familiar* might also fit the bill. As in:

> unduly intimate; too personal; taking liberties; presuming: The
>   duchess disliked familiar servants.

Source: meaning #5 [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/familiar).

Comment: Please see our Help Center’s directions on [How to reference material written by others](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) work by others. Please also provide an explanation, not just text copied in from elsewhere. We are not a link-aggregator; we expect answers to consist mostly of your own words. Answers without explanation may be deleted.